# .net core 2.2 service on Google Cloud slow start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a small .NET Core 2.2 web app and have to deploy it on Google Cloud. It works fine but it's extremely slow to start.

During deployment the `gcloud app deploy` command is stuck on

```
Updating service [my-fancy-app] (this may take several minutes)...
```

for a very, very long time.

I suspect it has to do with the liveness/readiness healthchecks settings in my app.yaml ... although the app is configured without any particular check, it's returning a straight 200.

Here are my current settings:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
service: my-fancy-app
env_variables:  
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
automatic_scaling:  
  min_num_instances: 1
liveness_check:
  path: "/_ops/public/healthz"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 3
  success_threshold: 1
readiness_check:
  path: "/_ops/public/healthz"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 5
  failure_threshold: 5
  success_threshold: 1
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

I tried reducing the value for `readiness_check.app_start_timeout_sec` to 60 but that caused the whole deployment to fail.

Suggestions?

Comment: How long does a deployment take on average? Flexible environments typically take much longer than standard due to resources being provisioned from the scratch each time. Also try to deploy with --log-http flag, it might show what exactly makes update operation take so long.

Comment: the time taken varies, on average is around 5-6 minutes, most of them spent on that `Updating service [my-fancy-app] (this may take several minutes)...` . I added ` --log-http` as you suggested and as I was suspecting it's poking the gcloud server for the current status. No clue on what is actually happening over there though :(

Comment: Well, not to be cheeky, but 5-6 minutes falls within the bounds of "this may take several minutes".

Comment: oh absolutely :D I was just hoping there was the possibility to speed up the process a bit. I was deploying the same service to a k8s cluster on AWS and there the process takes less than 2 minutes